# insert the webview in android fragment

Tags: android, webview, tabs

I am not able to insert a fragment in a tab android, would help when open, nothing appears is blank –

```
public class AndroidMobileAppSampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://mobile-sample-app.heroku.com");
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to insert a fragment in a tab android, would help when open, nothing appears is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // view.loadUrl(url); REMOVE!!!
    return false;
}
```

Comment: is giving the following error
mainWebView can not be a resolved or is not a field